# Simultaneous downloads with Tasks and WebClients

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am doing something completely wrong or just don't understand the concept of multithreading/tasking. I want, lets just say, 5 tasks running simultaneously downloading strings from the internet. On the console it should instantly place the 5 logs but they are not instant. Sorry for my horrible explanation but hopefully my code will clear things up.

```
class ThreadedDownloadWorker
{
    public Dictionary<string,string> urls { get; set; }
    public List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
    public string downloadGuid;
    public int progress = 0;
    public MainForm main;
    public int amountOfPages;

    public ThreadedDownloadWorker(MainForm main, int amountOfPages)
    {
        this.main = main;
        this.amountOfPages = amountOfPages;
    }

    public void startDownloadStrings(int maxAmountOfThreads, string downloadGuid)
    {
        this.downloadGuid = downloadGuid;
        for (int i = 0; i < maxAmountOfThreads; i++) 
        {
            if (urls.Count > 0) 
            {
                KeyValuePair<string, string> selectedUrl = urls.First();
                Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => doDownloadStrings());
                tasks.Add(task);
            }
        }
    }

    public void doDownloadStrings() 
    {
        KeyValuePair<string, string> selectedUrl = urls.First();
        urls.Remove(selectedUrl.Key);
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        Console.WriteLine("Started download: " + selectedUrl.Key);
        string downloadedString = wc.DownloadString(selectedUrl.Value);
        SettingsAndData.saveDownloadPage(downloadGuid, selectedUrl.Key + ".json", downloadedString);
        progress++;
        this.main.blogs[this.main.selectedGuid].status = "Downloaded " + progress + " / " + this.amountOfPages.ToString();
        this.main.reloadBlogGridThreaded();
        wc.Dispose();
        if (urls.Count > 0) 
        {
            //doDownloadStrings();
        }
    }
}
```

And this is how I call this code:

```
var amountOfPages = 28;     
Classes.ThreadedDownloadWorker threadedWorker = new Classes.ThreadedDownloadWorker(this, amountOfPages);
threadedWorker.urls = new Dictionary<string, string>();
for(int i = 0; i < amountOfPages; i++)
{
    threadedWorker.urls.Add((i * 50).ToString(), "http://justarandompage.bla.bla/?offset="+ (i * 50).ToString());
}
threadedWorker.startDownloadStrings(5, selectedGuid);
```

From my understanding this should start 5 download tasks at once. But when I check the console they are not instantly started, but instead start one after another, with maybe a 500ms delay between each.

Comment: `WebClient` is a good behaving citizen in the HTTP world, which means that it follows HTTP guidelines - no more than two simultaneous connections to the same server. If you're testing your application against one HTTP server, you'll never run more than two requests in parallel. Aside from that, why would you use *multi-threading* to issue concurrent requests? Just use asynchronous I/O, no need for extra threads.

Comment: Is there another method I can use to bypass this problem?

Comment: Why is it a problem? What are you trying to do, exactly?

Comment: I am using multithreading because i already tried the Async version of the WebClient. That also did not work. But that should be because of the 2 http requests limit. If that's the case I will rollback my code to the async one. But still won't solve my issue. Is it even possible to create more than 2 requests or dus the server i receive from also block that ?

Comment: @Luaan I am trying to receive a lot of json files from a server as fast as possible.

Comment: It's a process-wide setting IIRC - and quite often, the server has its own limit as well. It's designed to prevent exactly the thing you're trying to do - disrupt service for everyone else (regardless of whether that's your actual intent or not). If it's your server, add some method to download all the files as a batch. If it's not... just follow the rules.

Comment: Okay great. So my code should work as intended when i give my downloader multiple urls to multiple http servers?

Comment: Yes. The limit only applies to connections to the same server (or, to be more exact, the same IP endpoint IIRC).

Answer (score 1):

try using service point manager, and set default connection limit

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

this will remove the limitation of only two connections

Comment: I will also give this a try. Thank you :)